# Base search/find functionality (Ctrl+F) in AX 2009/2012 doesn't work properly...how to fix?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I feel like I might be losing my mind...but if you search the AOT for anything with double colons "::", it fails completely.  I'm trying to step through the Forms\SysAotFind to figure this out but I didn't want to spin my wheels a bunch for something that might be on my system only.

To reproduce in AX 2009, select Classes\SalesTableType, press Ctrl+F and put "CustLedgerAccounts::sumAccount" in the containing text box and click find now. You can see this is clearly located in the Classes\SalesTableType\accountCust method. I've tried searching for base enums inside objects with no luck either.

Comment: Wow, I had noticed the same and have always worked around it. Great question. Maybe change the wording "search functionality" to "find... functionality" to help people in future, I suspect this has cause a lot of people problems!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed the same behavior, but escaping the colons with a backslash makes the search work correctly.

So in your case you would need to search for "CustLedgerAccounts\:\:sumAccount".

Answer (score 5):

The search uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in the syntax defined by the [match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa886279.aspx) function.
Colon is a special character, hence it needs to be escaped by a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for a fix, you can see where the issue is here and just tweak it if you want to allow specifically for double colons:

```
[c]    \Classes\SysTreeNodeSearch\isNodeInRange     #46

        if (!match(containingText,source))
            return false;
```